# How to Trigger Callbacks on Flutter Bottom Navigation Bar Page Changes with Stateful Pages: Implementing Callbacks Between Two Classes

Tags: flutter, dart, callback, state

I have a flutter application with a bottom navigation bar that keeps page states in the navigation (I use go_router). I've been trying for a long time to get a callback on my fav page as soon as I arrive on the page. But I can't, so here's an outline of what I'd like:

Page 1 (which manages navigation):

```
void _tabChanged() {
   ...
}
...
LazyIndexedStack(
              index: _controller.index,
              children: const [
                Home(),
                Fav(), // it should be sent the callback, linked with tabChanged()
              ],
            ),
```

And for the page, you'd have to receive the callback:

```
const Fav({Key? key, required this.callback}) : super(key: key);
...
widget.callback() {
... here I receive the callback from tab.dart
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much PurplePolyhedron, I received an error so here's how I did it in the end:

```
GlobalKey<FavState> key = GlobalKey<FavState>();
void _handleTabChanged() {
  if (_tabController.index == 1) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (key.currentState != null) {
        key.currentState!.test();
      }
    });
  }
  ...
}
...
LazyIndexedStack(
  index: _controller.index,
    children: [
      const Home(),
      Fav(
        key: key,
      ),
    ],
),
```

and in the Fav page:

```
void test() {
    setState(() {
      ...
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the navigation bar to call some method of the `State<Fav>`. You can find the state using a `GlobleKey`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final key = GlobalKey();
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        MyWidget(key: key),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              (key.currentState as _MyWidgetState).change();
            },
            child: const Text("Change"))
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int counter = 0;
  void change() {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Counter: $counter");
  }
}
```

Or you can pass a `Listenable`, subscribe to it in `Fav`, and trigger the callback in navigation bar.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyPage> createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  late ChangeNotifier notifier;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notifier = ChangeNotifier();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    notifier.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        MyWidget(notifier: notifier),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: notifier.notifyListeners, child: const Text("Change"))
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChangeNotifier notifier;
  const MyWidget({super.key, required this.notifier});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int counter = 0;
  void change() {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.notifier.addListener(change);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.notifier.removeListener(change);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Counter: $counter");
  }
}
```

However, the best practice is to separate the logic from the widget tree instead of doing everything in `State`